# How did gboard integrate gif and emojis in their keyboard app as a keyboard extension

Tags: android, ios

Can a developper explain to me how gboard can have emojis and gifs integrated in their keyboard app which is integrated in a user's phone as a keyboard extension?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.1.html#img-kbd

Comment: Wow thanks. Is this possible for the ios?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: @CommonsWare  I would like to hire you so that you can create a similar keyboard extension for Android

Comment: Um, I pointed you to Android's implementation already: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.1.html#img-kbd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically they've implemented a complete IME, similar to what's shown in this sample: https://developer.android.com/samples/CommitContentSampleIME/index.html

Not all applications accept images sent from the keyboard, but it's getting more common. To overcome that limitation on some messaging apps, you can give your users the option of selecting an emoji/image/etc and sharing it to the relevant app, through the standard system sharing features, basically by bundling a regular app with your custom IME from where they can do that.

Btw, let me know if you'd like more details - me and my team developed a complete app for both Android and iOS do achieve just this, and can provide more details if needed.

Comment: I will contact you as soon as I can so that you can create a similar app for me on both ios and android. I will hire you on freelancer.com